# Algebraic Topology into computers.

Tags: algebraic-topology, algorithms

I started studying algorithms about CW-complexes and some stuff about discrete morse theory, but I want to know more about how are understood or how are inputed the spaces in the computer. Could anyone give me references about how people work the CW-complexes and graphs in the computer?

Comment: Matveev's textbook "Algorithmic Topology and Classification of 3-Manifolds" might be of interest.

Comment: Try Homological algebra prgramming at http://hamilton.nuigalway.ie/

Answer (score 0):

This link is outdated but might help: https://calculus123.com/wiki/Homology_software.